# Thymeleaf fragment expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, thymeleaf

I am using thymeleaf to split my templates in head/main/footer parts. In order to include stylesheets and javascript on some pages (but not on others) I am using fragment expressions [as explained here.](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thymeleaf3migration.html)

So my **head.html** looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head th:fragment="head(title,links,scripts)">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <title th:replace="${title}">Title placeholder</title>

    <!--/* Per-page placeholder for additional links */-->
    <th:block th:replace="${links} ?: ~{}" />
    <th:block th:replace="${scripts} ?: ~{}" />
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is used for instance in my homepage, **index.html** as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:replace="head :: head(~{::title},~{::link},~{::script})">
    <title th:text="#{label.pages.home.title}">Homepage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/jumbotron.css"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

This works fine as is. Script and link tags appear in the header of the resulting page. However occasionally I want to have scripts at the end of the body (just before `</body>`. If I put a `<script>....</script>` in that position two things happen in the resulting page.

- the script appears in the head
- the script appears a second time in its original position

How can I prevent thymeleaf from putting the script in the head?

Answer (score 0):

Fragment expression has syntax `~{template :: selector}`. You reference for original file and syntax reduced to `~{:: selector}`. Selector is XPath or CSS like expression. To prevent inclusion of all scripts you should narrow scope to `head` tag: `~{:: head/script}`.